# Picamera on Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit

Tags: ubuntu, picamera, v4l2, mmal

Is there any way to get picamera to work on Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit. I have tried:

1. Compiling a non-official version of userland for 64-bit and it compiled, but the camera does not work
2. I have tried using V4L driver instead with no success
3. Different camera and connector
4. Made sure start_x and gpu_mem are set in the boot config files

Does anyone have any guidelines on how to setup picamera Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit or if this is even possible?